# Empty array in json-server not receiving initial value

Tags: javascript, angular

Empty array in json file is not geting populated if at leat 1 object already exists

technologies used json-server & Angular 7 in a CRUD project

```
//Generate article id then create article
this.articleService.getAllArticles()
  .subscribe(articles => {

    //Generate article id    
    let maxIndex = articles.length - 1;
    let articleWithMaxIndex = articles[maxIndex];
    let articleId = articleWithMaxIndex.id + 1;
    article.id = articleId;

    //Create article
    this.articleService.createArticle(article)
      .subscribe(successCode => {
        this.statusCode = successCode;
        this.getAllArticles();
        this.backToCreateArticle();
      },
        errorCode => this.statusCode = errorCode
      );
  });
```

The issue seems to be the case when maxIndex is -1 // let maxIndex = articles.length - 1; 
as the article.length is zero then maxIndex = -1.
I have tried in many ways to rewrite the code without success

Comment: Why don't you add a conditional to check if the array is empty? Also, your question does not clarify what is the expected behavior if `articles` is an empty array, what value do you want to assign to the ID in that case? `1`?

Comment: Hi Raul, Yes the expected behavior should be that the initial object pushed in the array should have an assigned "id": 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if the array is empty at the beginning of your code.

```
// Generate article id then create article
this.articleService.getAllArticles()
  .subscribe(articles => {

    // Generate article id
    if (!articles.length) {

        article.id = 1;

    } else {

        article.id = articles[articles.length - 1].id + 1;
    }

    // Create article
    this.articleService.createArticle(article)
      .subscribe(successCode => {
        this.statusCode = successCode;
        this.getAllArticles();
        this.backToCreateArticle();
      },
        errorCode => this.statusCode = errorCode
      );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

my code wasn't working as I was using zero instead of null :(

```
if (this.maxIndex == 0) {
           this.articleId = 1;

} else {
  let articleWithMaxIndex = articles[this.maxIndex];
  let articleId = articleWithMaxIndex.id + 1;
  article.id = articleId;
```